# Prevent a sql query from browsing the table again

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I have a sql query that will browse my table "providers" to find available providers.It will look for the first 5, if they are not available, it will look for the next 5, etc.

Currently my problem is that when it gets to the end of the table, it starts again from the beginning of the table, so it's going to look for the first 5 again, then the next 5, and so on, endlessly.

How can I prevent this? I would like it to stop when it gets to the end of the table. Thank you very much.

**EDIT : MY CODE**

Here is my query :

```
SELECT sp FROM App\Entity\ServiceProvider sp
JOIN sp.user u
WHERE (JSON_CONTAINS(sp.benefits, :benefit$key) = 1
AND u.isActive = :isActive
ORDER BY sp.score DESC, sp.revenue DESC, sp.isBoosted DESC
LIMIT  :offset,5
```

And offset changes if the first 5 are not available, etc.

Comment: Please post your code..

Comment: Of course, here is above.

Comment: Is anyone there?